# Combine !Sub with !GetAtt in YAML Format

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

```
export VAR_HOST=
- !GetAtt
   - ElasticacheCluster
   - ConfigurationEndpoint.Address

export VAR_PORT= 
- !GetAtt
   - ElasticacheCluster
   - ConfigurationEndpoint.Port
```

Comment: Hello everyone, could someone suggest on below

Comment: You havent asked a question yet. Please consider editing your question.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use !GetAtt. You can just do the following:

```
UserData: !Sub |
   export VAR_HOST=${ElasticacheCluster.ConfigurationEndpoint.Address}
   export VAR_PORT=${ElasticacheCluster.ConfigurationEndpoint.Port}
```